# Tensor Flow tutorial logloss implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to study TF in the express way and i cant understant this part:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

It's explained with this: First, tf.log computes the logarithm of each element of y. Next, we multiply each element of y_ with the corresponding element of tf.log(y). **Then tf.reduce_sum adds the elements in the second dimension of y, due to the reduction_indices=[1] parameter. Finally, tf.reduce_mean computes the mean over all the examples in the batch.**

Why it does this manipulations, which are marked bold? why do wee need  another dimensiom? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two dimensions because cross_entropy computes values for a batch of training examples. Therefore, the dimension 0 is for a batch, and dimension 1 is for different classes of a specific example. For example, if there are 3 possible classes and batch size is 2, then y is a 2D tensor of size (2, 3).

Comment: On that tutorial, y_ is a [n, 10] matrix and y is a [10] vector. So `y_ * tf.log(y)` should be a [n] vector. `reduction_indices=[1] ` seems redundant because there is no 2nd dimension. Or, think about it another way, there is only 1 element on the 2nd dimension. Reduction always return that 1 element.